# Have systemd not kill your service if it is in a state it should not be killed

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I have a question regarding the configuration of a systemd service.

The service application is an application the controls a machine. Within the application the SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT and SIGHUP are captured. When the machine is "RUNNING", these signals are ignored and the application is not exited. If the machine is in "STOPPED" mode, the controlling application is exited.

We want to boot this application together with Linux, so we added the application as a systemd service.

We have the following configuration so far:

```
[Unit]
Description=Machine control service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=simplemachine
Group=simplemachine
CPUSchedulingPolicy=other
LimitRTPRIO=80
LimitRTTIME=infinity

WorkingDirectory=/opt/simplemachine/bin/
ExecStart=/opt/simplemachine/bin/simplemachine
KillMode=none
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I have the following questions.
When I perform:

```
sudo systemctl stop machine.service
```

I would like systemctl to send a SIGTERM, this way the application is only stopped when it is allowed to stopped.
Also when the application does not stop. It would be nice that systemctl does not kill the process, but for example returns some kind of fault or timeout code meaning that it may not stop the process.

How can I achieve this with the new systemd system?

Comment: That is just a shot in the dark, is ExecStop usefully in some way? for example by creating a shell script that will consider the importance of this(I am not very sure if systemd at end will not try to crazy stop your service). How can someone dislike this post. It is a genuine question.

Answer (score 11):

This answer is primarily based on the documentation for [systemd.kill](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html), but has been updated after doing some tests. It is admittedly not a perfect solution to this problem.

By setting [`SendSIGKILL=no`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#SendSIGKILL=) in your unit file, it is possible to prevent the process from being killed. To allow the initial `SIGTERM` to be sent, you will likely need to restore the `KillMode` option to its default value, which is `control-group`.

With these settings, running `systemctl stop machine.service` should work like this:

1. Because there are no `ExecStop=` commands specified in the unit file, a `SIGTERM` is sent to the process.
2. After a period of 90 seconds (`DefaultTimeoutStopSec`), `systemd` considers terminating the process forcefully.
3. Because `SendSIGKILL` is set to `no`, `SIGKILL` (`FinalKillSignal`) is **not** sent to the process, and the process continues running.

In effect, the only signal sent to the process on `systemctl stop` will be `SIGTERM`. Since the handling of `SIGTERM` is handled within the application itself, `systemctl stop` should work as intended: stops the application when the remote machine is down, times out when the remote machine is up.

The problem with this approach is noted by Michał Politowski in the comments. Namely, `systemd` will consider the unit to be failed once the stop timeout expires. This doesn't affect the process itself, but it will alter systemd's perspective of the process. If you issue another 'systemctl start' command while the unit is in this state, you'll end up with two processes.

The `KillMode=none` option that you already used avoids the process killing logic altogether. However, the results are similar to this approach. The state of the unit changes to inactive, while the processes continue to run.

As an additional note, the 90 seconds timeout can be configured with [`TimeoutStopSec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStopSec=).

Comment: Unfortunately while the process will indeed not be killed, systemd will consider the unit to be failed in such a situation. This likely may not be what the OP would want.